# All linear functions are homogeneous of degree one?

Tags: functions

I was looking through the Wikipedia page of "Homogeneous functions" and it stated that any linear function that maps V onto W is homogeneous of degree one. However, when I try to apply the definition of a homogeneous function to a line defined by one variable "*v*" and a non-zero constant "*z*":

*f(v)=v+z*

*f(tv)=(tv)+z*

*f(tv)=t(v+z/t)≠tf(v)*

I find that the line is not homogeneous.

So why is it that a linear function is always homogeneous even though the example I gave shows that it's not? What conceptual/calculation mistake did I make in in the process?

Comment: By the definition in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences) though your function wouldn't be a linear map anymore. The page on (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) defines "linear function" either as a polynomial of degree 0 or 1 (that is, $y=ax+b$ or $y=c$) or a linear map. For the above problem, the *linear maps* must have been meant. Article should be updated for clarity though.

Comment: See the definition of "linear function" that applies to vector spaces.  I assume $V,W$ are vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

a homogeneous function is a polynomial function  which all the
terms have the same degree. then in your example (in this case of
one dimension) $v \rightarrow av + z$ is not a homogeneous
polynomial since $z$ is a vector constant, not a variable.